# Updating database objects that have foreign collections?

Tags: android, ormlite, foreign-collection

I'm trying to think of how to get around this problem. I have an ORMlite object that can belong to multiple Categories; I'm using another table (i.e. a ForeignCollection) to track many-to-many connections between my objects and categories.

The problem is if I update the object with changed categories, the new categories are added, but old ones are not removed.

In the JavaDoc for the [update method of DAO](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#update%28T%29) I see this text:

> NOTE: Typically this will not save changes made to foreign objects or
>   to foreign collections.

My question is about the use of the word "typically." Does this mean that there IS a way through some sort of setting to make sure that updates update related foreign objects/collections?

Or should I read the sentence as if "typically" was not there, assume there is no automatic method, and that I need to run extra queries on committing each object to delete old categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is if I update the object with changed categories, the new categories are added, but old ones are not removed.

So you have an object that has a foreign collection of categories:

```
@ForeignCollectionField
ForeignCollection<Category> categories;
```

If you run `categories.add(category1)` or `categories.remove(category1)`, then the underlying collection should remove those from its associated table using a built-in DAO.

If you are changing the category list some other way then you are going to have to remove the `Category` entries by hand using the `categoryDao` directly.

> ... about the use of the word "typically." Does this mean that there IS a way through some sort of setting to make sure that updates update related foreign objects/collections?

Not sure why I left the word "typically" there.  I think it was a blanket statement to take into account the various auto-create, auto-refresh, etc. field settings -- I'm not sure.  In any case, I've removed it from the code base.

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) has no way to know if foreign objects have been changed.  It does not create magic proxy objects nor sessions so that it can tell when a foreign object has been updated.  You have to be explicit about what you want updated when.  The [documentation on foreign collections](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection) is quite explicit about it.

Comment: Thanks @Gray. I didn't think of doing it through Java. Still, that doesn't necessarily help... I have to process hundreds of objects which might either be new or updated in the database. I considered many possibilities which didn't work... and ended up using Transactions to delete all the categories in a list of the batch of recently updated objects, then re-add all the categories in that batch. It's wasteful as some object's categories may not have been changed, but the best I could do.

Comment: How about some sort of dirty flag @Chad.  Then whenever any of your fields are set you can check to see if they need to be updated or something.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @ChadSchultz So you say that we have to manually delete the data in the foreign collection from the database and then add the modified collection to the object? What do you mean with "batch"?

Answer (score 2):

OrmLite will not save objects to ForeignCollections automatically. You have to store and delete these objects yourself. Ormlite will retrieve the objects in the ForeignCollection automatically for you, provided you set the right parameters in the annotation.

Ormlite is "lite". It does ORM, but not completely. It's not JPA or Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the new Category to the table Categories directly, instead of adding a new category to the Object's foreignCollection. 
This can be done by simply creating a category ado and adding a new element.
A `newCategory.setObject(object)` is needed in order to create the relation with the object.

Hope this helps.